# Running update of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to use a DataFrame to manage data from many trials of an experiment I'm controlling with Python code. Ideally I will have one master dataframe with a row for each trial that lives in the main function namespace, and then a separate dict (or dataframe) returned from the function that I call to execute the important bits of code for each trial.

What is the best way to do a running update of the master dataframe with this returned set of data? So far I've come up with:

```
df = df.append(df_trial, ignore_index=True)
```

or

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_trial])
```

But neither seem ideal (and both take a relatively long time according to %timeit). Is there a more Pandonic way?

Answer (score 1):

You should build a list of the pieces and concatenate them all in one shot at the end.